# Can someone tell me what people used to build these websites?

Tags: vb.net, wordpress

Easy question, but I am a newbie:

Can someone tell me what CMS (like, uh, Wordpress) these two web sites use to make their slick designs:

http://annalisanatalimurri.com/
http://www.clarissabonet.com/

I've been mostly working in Wordpress, but seeing the simplicity of the code underneath (using Inspect Element) is convincing me to work in this medium.

Comment: The first site uses ViewBook, and the second SquareSpace. The CMS doesn't really matter too much, you should be able to create a nice slick site like that using wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You're able to design pages like that in practically any CSM that lets you style/write themes with CSS. If you don't want to write CSS and still use wordpress you can find simple and clean themes in the wordpress themes directory: https://wordpress.org/themes